# How to make a div dynamically size to screen height with dynamic header

Tags: html, css

I have three parts to my main page

- A nav bar
- An announcement bar
- The main content

As the content of the announcements are dynamic, I have trouble figuring out how to size the main content to the rest of the body.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">..nav content..</div>
<div id="announcements"><p>some text here</p></div>
<div id="content-wrap"></div>
```

I have tried to measure the height of the nav and announcements and then do `height:calc(1vh - 15px)`, however this will be inaccurate when the announcements change.

Thank you

Comment: do you have snippet or jsfiddle demo?

Comment: @mmativ please see https://oastem.org/ - you can observe the slight overflow

Comment: try to use `vh`

Comment: does your announcement wrap changes height? if not, try this: `.calendar-wrap {
    height: calc(100vh - 139.25px);
}`

Comment: @Ron.Basco yes, it does change height